# css - position img under h6 that will not be affected by h6 size

Tags: html, css, web, css-position, padding

I have an `img` under a `h6` in a template, and I have multiple appearances of this template.

The `h6` size could be 1 line, two lines etc.  As for now I have the `img` css like that:

```
ul.hourly li img {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

The problem is obviously that if the `h6` size is 2 lines in one of the templates and on other ones its 1 line, the `img`'s will not be on the same height.

How can I ahve the `img` with a fixed location, no matter what the `h6` size is?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you try giving the image a fixed height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add both the `h6` and the `img` in same container, and give it `position: relative`, and position the `img` according to that:

```
<div class="container">
   <h6>My title</h6>
   <img src="image.png"/>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container {
   position: relative;
}

.container img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
}
```

So always the `img` will be positioned at the bottom of the container.